# How to define a TikZ arrow macro with custom label as an argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-arrows

I want to define a custom arrow shape as a `\newcommand` macro that takes one argument, the label that should appear to the right of the arrow. However the following code doesn't work in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{1}{
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{\node [draw, fill=orange, single arrow, 
minimum height=3.5ex, single arrow head extend=1ex,
rotate=-90, right] {#1};}
}
```

I get the following error:

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode. Missing \begin{document}.
```

Comment: You need square brackets around the first instance of 1, not `{}`.  `\newcommand{\arrowdown}[1] ...` See [\newcommand argument confusion](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/117358) for some explanations of the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Alan, use `[]` instead of `{}` while defining `newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\newcommand{\arrowdown}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{\node [draw, fill=orange, single arrow,
minimum height=3.5ex, single arrow head extend=1ex,
rotate=-90, right] {#1};}
}

\begin{document}
\arrowdown{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

[image]